# Where to find the compiled css file in a React application?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, sass

I know that in Blazor, if Web Compiler is installed, then all the scss files can be compiled and output into a css file, say I have `Sidebar.scss`, `Card.scss`, `Tile.scss`, then they could be compiled to 1 css file called `site.css`.

Q1: Is there a way to do similar thing as above to output 1 css file contains all compiled css?

Q2: I now have 1 scss file for each component, but I cannot find the compiled css files for each of them, i.e. I cannot see a `Sidebar.css` compiled from `Sidebar.scss`.

EDIT: I'm using node-sass as introduced here https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet/, so for `Sidebar.js`, I have `Sidebar.scss` and when the scss file is saved, the style automatically applies

Answer (score 0):

See in react native, styling works diferently, Its not CSS which you apply, rather first you import Stylesheet:

1.`import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";`

Then you create styles from stylesheet like :

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: "#eaeaea"
  },
  title: {
    marginTop: 16,
    paddingVertical: 8,
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: "#20232a",
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: "#61dafb",
    color: "#20232a",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  }
});
```

So its similiar to css , but not exactly CSs, so you wont find any. compiled css , as this is a feature and inbuilt component of react native.

YOu can always transrom your sass/scss into react native style by using this [sass-transformer](https://github.com/kristerkari/react-native-sass-transformer)

It takes scss like:

```
.myClass {
  color: blue;
}
.myOtherClass {
  color: red;
}
```

and converts it to

```
var styles = {
  myClass: {
    color: "blue"
  },
  myOtherClass: {
    color: "red"
  }
};
```

Hope its clear. feel free for doubts

Comment: I did not know this, I am using node-sass and directly import the `scss` file into the `js` file, once the scss file is saved, it's automatically compiled and applied in the React application

Comment: So you can transform with the link i gave you. Just check that library. Hope it helps. And do upvote and mark as accepted if it helped. Thanks

Comment: @GauravRoy He is asking about React not React Native.